Measure distance via laser sensor
I am trying to measure the distance via a laser sensor (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Laser_Sensor)
But I am a bit confused by the description, it seems that the laser only detects if an object is near or far but doesn't actually return the distance. As an output it only provides a single digital pin.
Is there any way to get the actual distance or is it a purely binary sensor?

refer to the laser sensor datasheet

It either senses light reflected back or doesn't, and gives you a binary result.
From the FAQ on your link : Can it be used for distance measurement - No.
Please note it sends out infrared laser light that is invisible to eyes. There is no indication what power level it uses, is it below level of eye damage, or how anyone could order it because the paperwork about laser safety is missing so it will be caught at customs if you try to import it yourself. Depends where you live and if your country allows buying potentially dangerous products or not.

Fwiw the page says it's 650nm, and the "laser tube" is described in the schematic as "LED 2" so I suspect it's really just a blinking LED.
